# Similar overrides on 2 different listeners

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am a beginner at Java and as not as familiar with its syntax as compared to C.

Specifically I have the follow code; there are 2 `TextViews` `view1, view2`, and I make the same  `Toast` message pop up on clicking either `TextViews`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView view1, view2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_1a);
        view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        view2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_1b);
        view2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }   
        });
}   
}
```

I realised that if there are 100 `TextViews`, it will be inefficient if i keep overriding `onClick` 100 times.

As such, is there a way to override `onClick` just once, and let all instances of `setOnClickListener` to refer back to the same `onClick`?

Thanks!

Comment: use this: view.setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: Check this page out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Answer (score 1):

Define a class which implements `OnClickListener` along the lines of

```
class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

and then you can use the same class everywhere. For example:

```
// say you have 100 TextViews
for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++)
    views[i].setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the same message you can do it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView view1, view2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_1a);
        view1.setOnClickListener(listener);

        view2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_1b);
        view2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. What you are implementing are called "anonymous inner types".

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_1a);
view1.setOnClickListener(listener);
view2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_2a);
view2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Or you can create a subclass of the OnClickListener class, like @webuster answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably affect your listener to a variable and assign it to views :

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
};

view1.setOnClickListener(listener);

view2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the onclicklistener on each View but there is a cleaner way of doing so.

Put this in the Activity code:

```
    public void myOnclickListener(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Then set the click listener in your xml:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:onClick="myOnclickListener"
       />
```